# как вывести из базы данных названия отсортировав повторяющиеся Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

Я новичок в разработке, изучил азы ларавел и php myadmin. Меня интересует
как мне правильно вывести названия из таблицы если там есть повторяющиеся строки

к примеру:
table Fruits

```
id | id_text | fruit_name |

1 | 443 | яблоко
2 | 413 | яблоко
3 | 455 | груша
4 | 123 | яблоко
5 | 123 | слива
6 | 123 | апельсин
```

в конечном счёте мне нужно :
яблоко, груша, слива, апельсин

я обращаюсь к таблице и беру значение её ячейки  "fruit_name", далее я так понимаю нужно фильтровать это и выводить с помощью array_filter()?

```
$fruits_name =  Fruits::all();
/*$fruits_name =  Fruits::find('fruit_name');  возвращает null*/

    foreach ($fruits_name as $fruits) {

        /*$fruits->fruit_name вернёт все имена в формате string*/
    }
```

И корректно ли будет использование All()? Знаю про find(), но он что то не работает....Подскажите пожалуйста как правильнее сделать

Comment: Ищи `laravel select distinct`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Получаем только названия фруктов без повторяющихся записей:

```
$fruits_name =  Fruits::select('fruit_name')->distinct()->get();
```

Результатом будет Eloquent коллекция со списком всех фруктов.

Comment: да это то что нужно, спасибо вам!